Issue with PATCH request when trying to update the privacy status

Title: Issue with PATCH Request for Updating YouTube Video Privacy Status via API

Context:
I am attempting to change the privacy status of a YouTube video from public to unlisted using a PATCH request.

Endpoint:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status
Method:
PATCH
Authorization:
I am using a valid Bearer token with the youtube.force-ssl scope.
Request Body:
{
   "id": "rOWGJjUUZ6Q",
   "status": {
     "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
   }
}




What I Tried:

Verified the Video ID:
I confirmed that the video ID rOWGJjUUZ6Q exists by making a successful GET request to retrieve the video’s current status:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=rOWGJjUUZ6Q


Made a PATCH Request to update the video’s privacy status:
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status
Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AcM612w9X_EA90n_64XLBguIa_HMwqKpyK9TbZAnm-ky0CaSNzVGzivkmO9Vv_NJlhJziKWLNdEMoTpx5pE8vGjrPePBJmgIFqS2blQjWJsveSjsEeP7qKb8erKHqLvLoXUUZKccLgQQnGjidjTiH1vHhJi4JsnHhe2SoIfMagaCgYKAd8SARASFQHGX2MiAKjW6kcC6NjkyoI_Inm76A0177
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "rOWGJjUUZ6Q",
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
  }
}




What I Expected:
I expected the video’s privacy status to change from public to unlisted and receive a 200 OK response confirming the update.

What Happened:
Instead, I received a 404 Not Found response, even though the video ID is valid, the video exists, and the OAuth token has the necessary scope for modifying video status.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

Request:
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status
Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AcM612w9X_EA90n_64XLBguIa_HMwqKpyK9TbZAnm-ky0CaSNzVGzivkmO9Vv_NJlhJziKWLNdEMoTpx5pE8vGjrPePBJmgIFqS2blQjWJsveSjsEeP7qKb8erKHqLvLoXUUZKccLgQQnGjidjTiH1vHhJi4JsnHhe2SoIfMagaCgYKAd8SARASFQHGX2MiAKjW6kcC6NjkyoI_Inm76A0177
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "rOWGJjUUZ6Q",
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "unlisted"
  }
}


Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Found",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
  }
}




Tags:

#YouTubeAPI
#PATCHRequest
#VideoPrivacyStatus
#404Error
#OAuthPermissions



This question is similar to: Issue with PATCH Request for Updating YouTube Video Privacy Status via API. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
